# keras tensorflow load_weights fails

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using keras 1.2 with tensorflow 1.0.0 backend.

I have a function that loads a pre-calibrated model from json and then loads its weights from a hdf5 file.

```
def load():
    model = model_from_json(open(model_path).read())
    model.load_weights(model_weights_path)
```

This function, more precisely the call to `load_weights` results in the following exception:

```
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run()
```

I wonder if that is due to these lines that I put in the beginning of my module to set the tensorflow seed for reproducibility:

```
tf.set_random_seed(123) # To set Tensorflow seed
sess = tf.Session()
keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

It seems the keras session does not automatically set the loaded model as the graph associated to the session, hence failing to initialize the weights.

Any explanation and workaround to avoid the exception?

Comment: can you check double check if your actually reading data from model_path.

Comment: Data reading is done. If I switch backend o theano all works well. The problem comes from the session that I set to Keras for reproducibility purposes. When I load the model, it is not associated to that session

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much am using the same code as you and it works for me.

```
       from keras.models import Sequential
        from keras.models import Model
        from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Input, GlobalAveragePooling2D
        from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
        from keras.utils import np_utils
        from keras.models import model_from_json
        from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
        from keras.layers.pooling import AveragePooling2D
        from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
        from keras.layers.convolutional import ZeroPadding2D
        from keras.engine.topology import Merge
        from keras.layers import merge
        from keras.optimizers import Adam
        from keras import backend as K
        from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
        from keras.layers.convolutional import ZeroPadding2D

        import PIL
        import inception
        import tensorflow as tf
        import keras
        import glob
        import pandas as pd
        import pickle
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        from PIL import Image

     # load json and create model
        json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
        # load weights into new model
        model.load_weights("model.h5")
        print("Loaded model from disk")

model.summary()
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

score = model.predict(transfer_values_test)
```

Comment: The difference is that in the beginning of my module I create a tensorflow session and I set the keras session to be it, as I mention in my question. I am doing that to seed the random number generator of my session for reproducibility of results. It seems when I load the model, the graph does not get associated to that session which causes the exception

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it seems that Keras doesn't respect the session set by set_session when loading models.

Try forcing Keras to use a particular session by Tensorflow's context manager:

```
def load():
    with sess.as_default():    
        model = model_from_json(open(model_path).read())
        model.load_weights(model_weights_path)''
```

If Keras still complains, predefine a graph (`graph=tf.Graph()`) and force  model.load_weights to use it by introducing an additional `with` statement:

```
def load():
    with graph.as_default():
        with sess.as_default():    
            model = model_from_json(open(model_path).read())
            model.load_weights(model_weights_path)''
```